# MySQL Primary Key Design

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm planning on creating an "Organizations" table, where the columns are:

Organization Id (primary key), Name, Plan and Company Id (foreign key).

My issue is that per organization there can be multiple companies, that means, I would need to have multiple records with the same Organization Id but with a different Company Id, but since the Organization Id is my primary key I know I can't do this (because it's unique).

How can I structure/design this? It's essentially a one to many relationship between an organization and a company. I'm just starting out with MySQL so I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Drop companyId from the organisations table and have organisationId as foreign key in the companies table.

```
CREATE TABLE Organizations (
    OrganizationId INTEGER,
    ... other fields,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrganizationId)
)

CREATE TABLE Companies (
    CompanyId INTEGER,
    OrganisationId INTEGER,
    ... other fields,
    PRIMARY KEY (CompanyId),
    FOREIGN KEY (OrganisationId) REFERENCES Organizations(OrganisationId)
)
```